# Do Java's threads work like process on linux?

Tags: java, linux, jetty

I've started a jetty server and an ehcache instance, soon I encountered the thread limit on linux when I start another jave process.

The error message was `unable to create new native thread` (P.S. My linux OS is CentOS 6.2).

Then I used `ps -xH` to know that the two java processes(jetty and ehcache) spawn almost 800 threads, and the total number of `ps -xH` are 1023, `ulimit -u` shows 1024.

So, my question is that why the java spawn threads but I've encountered the limit of process numbers?

P.S. I have enough memory

Answer (score 3):

Because for Linux Threads an processes are basically the same thing.
The difference between them is that threads share things like memory, file descriptors and so on and processes do not.

Check [this](http://www.samba.org/~tridge/talks/threads.pdf) out for a more indepth insight. So threads and processes both count against your limit of 1023 proccesses.

You should probably try to create less threads, that seems like a huge amout to me.

Answer (score 0):

That is by far an excessive amount of threads, at least for Jetty. Unless you have stressed your server with hundreds of requests per second, this shouldn't be happening.  Double-check that the threads are not blocking indefinitely. In any case, configure the maximim number of threads allowed before enqueueing or rejecting a request.